# Declarative Jenkins Pipeline: How can I iterate the same stage for different repositories?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have several maven projects which are all treated in the same way to make a release.

Is it possible to reuse the same stage and iterate it just with a different repository name to clone?

```
stage('Maven_microservices') {
steps {

    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: "*/${env.BRANCH}"]], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], 
        [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'maven_microservice_1']], 
        submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'autouser',
        url: 'ssh://mygerrit:29418/maven/maven_microservice_1']]])

    container('maven') {                 
        configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'maven_settings', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
            dir('maven_microservice_1') {
                sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:update-parent'
                sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:resolve-ranges'
                sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:use-releases'
                sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS --batch-mode release:prepare'
            }
        }                                   
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this answer is what you need, but do you mean something like this?

```
['maven_microservice_1', 'maven_microservice_2'].each { projectName ->

  stage("${projectName}") {
    steps {

      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: "*/${env.BRANCH}"]], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], 
        [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: "${projectName}"]], 
        submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'autouser',
        url: "ssh://mygerrit:29418/maven/${projectName}"]]])

      container('maven') {                 
        configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'maven_settings', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
          dir("${projectName}") {
            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:update-parent'
            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:resolve-ranges'
            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:use-releases'
            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS --batch-mode release:prepare'
          }
        }
      }                                   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks very good, I'm going to try and will let you know. Thanks so much nogenius :)

Comment: It fails with the below error, does this syntax work in a declarative pipeline? Thanks!

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 60: expecting ')', found ',' @ line 60, column 34.
           ('maven_microservice_1', 'maven_microservice_2', 'maven_microservice_3', 'maven_microservice_4').each { projectName ->

Comment: Sorry, I think it is supposed to be a square bracket [...]. I corrected it above

Comment: Thanks, going to try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use of Jenkins Declarative Shared library can resolve this. Refer [Extending with Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

Create GenericMavenRelease.groovy in the library - vars folder and embed this code

```
def call(body){
    //evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def config = [:]
    def builder
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()


    pipeline{
        agent any
        stages{
            stage('Maven_Microservices'){
                steps{
                        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                        branches: [[name: "*/${env.BRANCH}"]], 
                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                        extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], 
                        [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: "${projectName}"]], 
                        submoduleCfg: [], 
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'autouser',
                        url: "ssh://mygerrit:29418/maven/${projectName}"]]])

                        container('maven') {                 
                        configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'maven_settings', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                          dir("${projectName}") {
                            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:update-parent'
                            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:resolve-ranges'
                            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS versions:use-releases'
                            sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS --batch-mode release:prepare'
                          }
                        }
                }
            }
            }
    }

}
```

Create Jenkinsfile as below in each repository

```
@Library('maven-library@1.0.0') _
GenericMavenRelease {
}
```

This way you follow DRY - Do Not Repeat Yourself and build the code with multiple repository with single pipeline code